# How to get nested items in a nested list structure in Java

Tags: java, list, nested-lists

I'd like to get all nested items from a structure which contains items itself and also items which contain items themselves:
When adding items to this lists, I don't know what kind of item it will be as I am only adding the general type of items (called SuperItem) to this list.
*(SubItem and Item as well inherit from SuperItem)*

For example, in the end I have a list of this SuperItems which looks like:

**SuperItem[SubItem A, SubItem B, Item C, SubItem D]**

Though, the Item C also contains SubItems. So if I have a nested structure which looks unfolded like this:

**UnfoldedSuperItem[SubItem A, SubItem B, SubItem C1, SubItem C2, SubItem C3, SubItem D]**

This is the list I want to get returned. Though, currently I can only get A, B and D from the SuperItem List but not C1, C2 and C3 when calling `getAllSubItems()`.

```
public class Item extends SuperItem{
    List<SuperItem> superItems;
    List<SubItem> subItems;

    public Item() {
        super();
        superItems = new LinkedList<>();
        subItems = new LinkedList<>();
    }


    public void addItem(SuperItem s) {
        if (!superItems.contains(s))    {
            superItems.add(s);
        }
    }

    //[... a remove method is also in this class, not included here as not in scope]

    public List<subItem> getAllSubItems() {
        for (superItem s: superItems) {
            if (s.getClass() == SubItem.class) {
                if (!subItems.contains(s)) {
                    subItems.add((SubItem) s);
                }
            } else {
                //if it is a item, somehow call the method getAllSubItems() on itself
            }
        }
        return subItems;
    }
}
```

The only thing that is missing here, is when I came to this C-Item which is not a sub-item. I kinda want to unwrap C to get all the nested items in there.

*Also what is important here:*
*Item can also contain Items itself. So the list can look also like this:*

SuperItem[Item A, Item B, Item C, SubItem D]

and unfolded then:

SuperItemUnfolded1[Item A1, Item A2, SubItem B1, SubItem B2, Item C1, Item C2, SubItem D]

and more unfolded then:

SuperItemUnfolded2[SubItem A1.1, SubItem A1.2, SubItem A2.1, SubItem A2.2,SubItem B1, SubItem B2, Item C1.2, etc. etc.])

Comment: Your problem description is quite confusing. I didn't get exactly what you have and what you want to get out of it. Can you rephrase it or make it a bit clearer?

Comment: @SHG I tried to rephrase it.
SuperItem is the super class from which Item and SubItem inherit. When adding a item, I don't know which kind of item is added (so weather it's a sub-item or a item which contains more sub-items)

Comment: Somehow I understand what you are trying to do, If you have specific SubItem which  may have SubItems itself, you can do simple check on each SubItem to see if it is a list itself (or may contain some contents with **Size() > 0** for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
public class SuperItem {
   List<Item> superItems = new LinkedList<Item>();
   List<Item> currentSubItems = null;


   public void addItem(Item s, boolean isNewSublist) {
      if (isNewSublist || currentSubItems == null) {
         currentSubItems = new LinkedList<Item>();
         superItems.add(currentSubItems);
      }
      if (!currentSubItems.contains(s))    {
         currentSubItems.add(s);
      }
      ...
   }

   public List<Item> getAllSubItems() {
      List<Item>subItems = new List<Item>();
      for (List<Item> superItem : superItems) {
         for (Item item : superItem.subItems) {
      ...
      return subItems;
   }
}
```

The details will vary depending on exactly what you want to accomlish, but basically it sounds like you:

1. Want a list of lists, containing "items".
2. You want to encapsulate this "list of lists" in a class.
3. The class should provide methods to "add" items, and to "list" items.
4. One thing I'm not clear about - should "items" be unique within a "sublist", or unique within the entire "list of lists" object?.  I chose the former.

You might also be interested in Java collections like [Dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_dictionary_class.htm), [Map](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm) or [Set](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm).

"Set" might be especially helpful to you:

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm
>
> A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. It
>   models the mathematical set abstraction.
>
> The Set interface contains only methods inherited from Collection and
>   adds the restriction that duplicate elements are prohibited.
>
> Set also adds a stronger contract on the behavior of the equals and
>   hashCode operations, allowing Set instances to be compared
>   meaningfully even if their implementation types differ.

Comment: Thank you... Regarding 4, when I get you right, I want that the items is unique within the entire list of lists object. Though, the issue is also that I want to getAllSubItems in the Item class not the super class (restricted by the task description). But I think if I try it with the boolean operator, it'll might help. In the end, its so confusing because the items themselves cannot only contain sub-items but also items themselves. So you have a list of lists and also not-list items. And this lists can also contain lists... 
(I didn't think about set- though the main problem remains the same)

Comment: Q: Exactly whats the "difference" between one "sublist" and another?  If you're not sure, then why even have sublists at all?  SUGGESTION: There's no reason you can't have "addItem()" add to *TWO* "lists": 1) a [Set](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm) object (to ensure "uniqueness" across *all* lists, and to simpllfy iterating "all items", and 2) Individual sub-lists (like you have now).  Please upvote/accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Edit: I solved the problem. The only thing I needed to do is in the else statement of my original code to call `subItems.addAll(s.getAllSubItems())`
though, I replaced the lists with set cause as you said, it makes for sense as I don't have to check for duplicates.